# Jasper Reports: how to add own Functions to Expression Editor

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using `Jaspersoft Studio` 6.6 and try to add own `functions` to the `Expression Editor`.

Therefore i follow the tutorial [Jaspersoft Studio Expression Editor: how to extend it and contribute your own functions (part 2) - updated for version 5.5](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jaspersoft-studio-expression-editor-how-extend-it-and-contribute-your-own-functions-part-2-0) (i was not able to find a more current version so i guess this one should be still correct)

All works fine but i had to replace the language of the generated report (`SampleFunctionsReport.jrxml`) from `groovy` to `java` to get rid of `class not found exceptions`

Finally the following Errors are remaining:

```
Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method HELLO_WORLD_MSG() is undefined for the type SampleFunctions_1541665022158_603382    SampleFunctionsReport.jrxml    /MyFunctions    line 37    JRXML Problem
The method HELLO_WORLD_MSG() is undefined for the type SampleFunctions_1541665022158_603382 value = HELLO_WORLD_MSG( );     SampleFunctionsReport.jrxml    /MyFunctions    line 0    JRXML Problem
The method REPEAT_MSG(String, int, boolean) is undefined for the type SampleFunctions_1541665022158_603382    SampleFunctionsReport.jrxml    /MyFunctions    line 52    JRXML Problem
The method REPEAT_MSG(String, int, boolean) is undefined for the type SampleFunctions_1541665022158_603382 value = REPEAT_MSG("A message that will be probably repeated",5,true);     SampleFunctionsReport.jrxml    /MyFunctions    line 0    JRXML Problem
```

I checked the points of the tutorial a couple of times...
can someone reproduce my problem?
What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<import value="test.customfunctions.*"/>
```

this is the code from my `jrxml`, which is fine.
when i tried to enter the full `class` name - i got an error, that the `package` cannot be added.

today i tried the same again - and its working. even the resulting `XML` is **identical**!